# Annotating protractor HTML test output with further information

Tags: jasmine, protractor

For my protrator tests I would like to provide additional information at the start of each test spec such as a links to test cases that have been written that the automated test covers.

Something like:

```
describe('Test Case ABC0001 - http://www.someinternalsite.com/testcases/bla', function(){
    describe('when performing X', function(){
        it('should to Z', function() {
            button.click();
            //other actions...
            expect(...).toEqual(...);
        });
    });
});
```

The idea being is that I would like the user to be able to navigate to test cases documented for each test suite I have written. So I need links to be rendered in the protractor HTML report being output at the end of my test runs.

Is it possible to have hyperlinks contained within Jasmine describe statements?

Comment: Have you tried [`protractor-html-reporter`](https://github.com/etxebe/protractor-html-reporter) - it looks like it would allow the markup in the describe/it descriptions be evaluated on an HTML report page.

Comment: Thanks, I am using `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` currently which looks like it does a similar thing from what I can tell. I tried embedding a <link> within the describe string value but it seems the closing </link> tag doesnt get included from what I can tell in the generated report